# Specialized Algorithm for Set-Cover with $k=3$

Tags: algorithms, set-cover

I know that the Set-cover problem with $n$ elements and a universe of size $N$ is NP complete. 
Also, the problem is has parameterized complexity regarding the number of sets $k$ that should cover the whole universe: 
There are only ${n \choose k}=\mathcal{O}(n^k)$ different combinations of $k$ subsets.

My specific problem is easily reducible to the set-cover problem with $k=3$. 
My approach that iterates over all ${n \choose k}=\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ subsets does not perform well enough.

Is there any specialized algorithm for the 3-set-cover problem?
Ideally, I would like some parameterized algorithm or some potent preprocessing techniques that exploit $k=3$.

Comment: You might be able to go down to $O(n^2)$ using a meet-in-the-middle approach, but it seems hard to go beyond that.

Comment: An algorithm running in time $n^k$ is not FPT for the parameter $k$, it is only an XP-algorithm. You need a running time of the form $f(k) n^{O(1)}$.

Comment: @juho true, I remembered incorrectly

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I would be very interested in a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm. I will try some meet-in-the-middle approach. Do you have a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ solution?

Comment: I don’t have such a solution in mind.

Comment: As a heuristic, you can use a data structure (such as a set-trie) supporting subset or superset queries to implement a meet-in-the-middle strategy, with the same worst-case complexity but potentially better real-case complexity.